# How to set CriteriaType to Date for a cell in googleAppcript?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have my active spreadsheet object as ss and given a Range R as shown below:

`R = "B2"`

I want to set its criteria type to Date as shown below something like:

`ss.getRange(R).setValidationCriteria('Date')`

so that when user clicks on that cell, they should be able to see the date picker calendar like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add Data Validation with `CriteriaType` as `date` using [DataValidationBuilder.requireDate()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation-builder#requiredate) method.

[Range.setDataValidation()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setdatavalidationrule) expects a [DataValidation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation) type argument.

**Sample Code:**

```
  var R = "B2";
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation()
      .setAllowInvalid(false)
      .requireDate()
      .build();

  sheet.getRange(R).setDataValidation(rule);
```

---

**Output:**

[image]